# Agregar un campo ForeingKey en un modelo de Django

Tags: django-models

tengo un modelo de Django con 3 tablas que están relacionadas: Indicadores, frecuencia y publicacion, para crear un formulario de carga y consulta de la cotización del dolar en los últimos años, pero cuando ejecuto "makemigrations" me da el siguiente error:

```
    **You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'indicadores' to publicacion without a default; we 
    can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
    Please select a fix:
     1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this 
    column)
     2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
    Select an option:**
```

La verdad es que soy nuevo en Django y no se como podría incluir los campos "foreignKey" sin problemas, este es el modelo:

```
    from django.db import models


    class Frecuencia(models.Model):
        codigo_frec=models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
        descripcion_frec=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Indicadores(models.Model):
        codigo_ind=models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
        nombre_ind=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        frecuencia=models.ForeignKey(Frecuencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    class Publicacion(models.Model):
        fecha_hora=models.DateTimeField()
        cotizacion=models.FloatField()
        indicadores=models.ForeignKey(Indicadores, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

... gracias de antemano